# Location.Replace and Clear cache Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, caching, routes

Problem:
Chrome caches too much data, so when i create entries like Post and Comment in my db, its isn't loaded, but all the existing entries are being displayed.

Chrome refuses to run through my script, and just displays it from cache, and therefor not showing the new entry.

I can solve this problem partly by using

```
Location.reload(true);
```

But when i create a post i route back to the overview of all posts, which isnt loaded properly from my API, since the new post isnt showing.

I route back to the overview with

```
Location.replace('../nyheder');
```

How do i clear cache while routing to another page?

Answer (score 0):

I rather think it is an issue with your HTTP -mainly response- headers. The headers will tell Chrome whether to fetch new data or use its cache.

You should use

```
If-none-match
```

and

```
ETag
```

Headers.